# Convert Android Color(int) to a .Net System.Windows.Media Color

Tags: android, wpf, colors

I am struggling with what should be a very simple task - converting the integer that represents an Android java color, which I save in a database, to a color that I can use in WPF. 
This has come closest:

```
        byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(intColor);
        Color bg = Color.FromArgb(bytes[0], bytes[1], bytes[2], bytes[3]);
```

The results I am getting are roughly:
**Android /  WPF**
Red /    Pink.
Green /  Blue.
Blue /   White.
Yellow / Blue.
Pink /   Cyan.

For example, this integer is Green in Android but Blue in WPF:-14942947

Sorry for the stupid question... Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

So a little debugging later and I see that the Bytes are reversed, so when you convert the int into a byte array, you will get the following:

alpha = bytes[3], Red = bytes[2], Green = bytes[1], Blue = bytes[0]

and the answer is:

Color bg = Color.FromArgb(bytes[3], bytes[2], bytes[1], bytes[0]);

Just in case anyone needs it. :)